# Filter out items by Date using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, localdate

I have a transaction table with a list of transactions by users with dates.

Transaction has an `amount` field and a `date` field.

I want to search the DB. And then I want to ***filter*** only transactions done today (*currentDate*) and ***sum*** the total of the amount.

I need help to write the stream that will group the transaction list by today's date and sum them.

The date is stored like this in my DB:

```
2022-05-16 20:54:48.110
```

*My attempt:*

```
BigDecimal totalDailyTransaction = findTransaction.stream()
    .map(Transaction::getTransactionAmount)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you query the db and store the values? As `String`s?

Comment: It's spring boot and I am using JPA. So I am finding the transaction table by userId then this will return a list of transactions. So I need to sum up the total of transactions carried out today—reasons why I need to group by today and sum using java8 stream. I have this presently but how to pass the date and do the sum is the problem.

Map<String, List<Transaction>> transactionByDate = transaction
                                        .stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Transaction::getTransactionDate)); @deHaar

Comment: What type does `getTransactionDate` return? Hopefully not a `java.util.Date`…

Comment: @deHaar the date was inserted with Instant.now(). So I can fetch it with String.

Comment: Please don't post the code in the comments, it needs to be present in the question (don't forget to apply the appropriate formatting).

Comment: *group the transaction list by today's date* - Can you clarify what do you mean by saying **group ... by today's date**? Does it imply that you need to **filter out** only transactions that have been made today, or you need to **group** transactions **by date**?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes I want to filter only transactions done today and sum the total of the amount. There is an amount field. So I want to sum then I can compare it with the user's daily limit. This is what I have now.

*` totalDailyTransaction = findTransaction.stream().map(Transaction::getTransactionAmount).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);`*

Comment: *The date is stored like this in my DB* I certainly hope it’s not stored as a `varchar` or `char`! Use `timestamp with time zone` or at least `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense. What you're proposing, based on the statement 'using java 8 streams' and 'get all transactions by a user **then** group' (emphasis mine) - is to query the database for a boatload of records, then toss away most of them.

Whyever would you do that?

The right move is to tell the database you want the sum (did you mean 'count'?) of column X for all rows which have date Y.

Note that databases store dates as dates. What you pasted is what the database is showing you, it doesn't store dates as strings. However, it does show that your transaction is a timestamp (as in, a specific moment in time, not just 'some day').

```java
public int getTransactionTotalOnDay(Connection con, LocalDate day) throws SQLException {
  try (var ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transaction WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?")) {

    ps.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(day.atStartOfDay()));
    ps.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.valueOf(day.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().minusSeconds(1)));

    try (var rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
       if (!rs.next()) return 0;
       return rs.getInt(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Java streams are irrelevant and would be ridiculously inefficient (as that would involve having the DB stream the entire table to your java process, only for java to then ignore most of that - databases have indices and can do these queries orders of magnitude faster by just looking up precisely the information you need).

Concepts used in this snippet:

- Raw JDBC database access - you may want to use a nicer abstraction such as JDBI or JOOQ.
- Prepared Statements and ResultSets *must* be safely closed, so we use the try-with-resources construct to ensure it happens.
- The only proper time API in java is the `java.time` package (that's where `LocalDate` is from. Unfortunately, JDBC predates it, so you need to convert things to JDBC-ness with `Timestamp.valueOf`. Hopefully your db and java server's ideas about 'current time zone' are identical or you'll need to write additional code.
- Just about any queries you send to a database that involve user input *must* use prepared statement, because otherwise you'll be vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. It's probably not neccessary here, but you might as well use the style that works for any user input.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ***filter*** only transactions done today (currentDate) and ***sum*** the total of the amount.

You need to apply `filter()` operation to retain only today's transactions in the pipeline.

And then apply `map()` to extract the transaction amount and `reduce()` to get the total.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Transaction> transactions = // initialing the source list

    BigDecimal totalDailyTransaction = transactions.stream()
        .filter(transaction -> isRecentTransaction(transaction))
        .map(Transaction::getTransactionAmount)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}

public static boolean isRecentTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    // date is stored like this: `2022-05-16 20:54:48.110`
    // we need the first part representing the current date in accordance with ISO-8601
    String date = transaction.getTransactionDate().split(" ")[0];
    return LocalDate.now().isEqual(LocalDate.parse(date));
}
```

As I understand from the snippet of code in the comment beneath the question (where you've mentioned `Map<String, List<Transaction>>`) the `date` attribute of the `Transaction` entity is of type `String` which isn't a bright idea. That's definitely a problem, although it's out of the scope of the question on how to build the stream pipeline. You might consider describing what prevents you from using `LocalDateTime` class in your entity with all related details, like which ORM you are using, etc. in the separate question.